# Permission denied when adding audit rule in audisp plugin

Tags: linux, selinux, auditd

I'm trying to write an audisp plugin on a Linux CentOS 7 VM. Instead of statically setting the audit rules via /etc/audit/rules.d/, I wanted to add rules dynamically in the plugin using libaudit interfaces (based on some system settings).

My code looks somewhat like the following:

`int fd_audit = audit_open();      // this is successful
if (audit_is_enabled(fd_audit) <= 0)
    audit_set_enabled(fd_audit, 1);  // "Permission denied" error given
}
else {
    // set some rules
}`

The problem I'm facing is with audit_set_enabled() function, as permission is denied, when SELinux is enforcing.
When SELinux is permissive, audit_set_enabled() returns a successful status but adding audit rule still fails.

I tried looking out for avc denied messages but can't seem to find any.

Any help or advice is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to solve above problem by disabling "don't audit" rules with
`sudo semodule -DB`.

Then I was able to get AVC logs and fix the sepolicy rules with `audit2allow`. Seems I was missing `netlink_audit_socket { read write }` access rights.